# Count equal strings in a list of string and make them unique

Tags: c#, string, count, cpu-word

I have a list of words which are bi-gram as an example:

```
welcome guys
guys and
and ladies
ladies repeat
repeat welcome
welcome guys
```

Now I want to count the equal strings and return get this output:

```
welcome guys, 2
guys and, 1
and ladies, 1
ladies repeat, 1
repeat welcome, 1
```

How can i do this in c#?

Comment: Anything have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Typically it is a good idea to explain or demonstrate what you have tried already.  As you can see from the down-votes some people get really butt-hurt when you don't.  That being said, this question seems pretty straight forward.  I am not sure demonstrating what you have tried already would elucidate the problem any further - maybe I am wrong.  Anyway, the down votes really seem unwarranted IMO.

Comment: Why does `repeat welcome` `return` `1` while both `repeat` and `welcome` have appeared before? What is the rule here?

Comment: thanks @JasonBoyd for your notes. I will do it.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Linq and the `GroupBy` function pretty easily:

```
var input = new string[]
    {
        "welcome guys",
        "guys and", 
        "and ladies",
        "ladies repeat",
        "repeat welcome",
        "welcome guys"
    };

var groups =
    input
    .GroupBy(x => x);

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", g.Key, g.Count().ToString());
}
```

> welcome guys, 2
>   guys and, 1
>   and ladies, 1
>   ladies repeat, 1
>   repeat welcome, 1

Comment: how can i return "var groups " ?
if i write:         public var countNgram(int ngram){...}
it prompts me an error which var should be local.
which type i should convert and then return it ?

Comment: The `var` keyword is an implicitly typed variable, meaning the compiler infers the type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx. Implicit variables can only be used in the local scope, as the error says.  You have to return an explicit type from a function.  In this particular case the explicit type of `var groups` is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>` but that is kind of ugly so you probably want to convert that to something else - maybe your own class..